# Add a captcha form to the woocommerce register form

Tags: plugins, user-registration, e-commerce

I am trying to find a way of adding a captcha form on the register form that woocommerce build.

I am able to create a template override but if i was to add the recaptcha directly i dont know what to do if it is correct etc.

I have tried adding the plugin easy captcha but that didn't show anything.

wp version is 3.7
woocommerce version is 2.0.20

Any ideas would be brilliant

thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found there is a hook that someone added:

```
<?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>
```

I found this in the git repo

Hope that line of code will help someone who struggles finding the answer i did

----EDIT----

When i looked into this more carefully the fix i did was add this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-captcha/

This then allows you to select where you want the captcha form to appear

Comment: CAn you describe the soultion more details???? Like, where to add the code and how??? Thanks.

Comment: I have changed my answer to what i did after actually looking into this more. not sure if i should remove what i had before. but my edit is how i fixed it